# Is there any testing method to apply one piece of testing code in python, to test two different programs with the same function?

Tags: python, testing

For example, if I write a program to implement a small game in Python, and another one implement the same game, our codes are almost the same, but the type of some parameters and implementation of some internal functions are not identical. I want to test our codes and compare them, how can I do this?

Comment: Get some sets of inputs and what their correct output is. Run the input with the game and see if you get the correct output with each implementation. If the game isn't deterministic, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as

```
# Some class that contains a `sum` implementation
class MethodA(object):
    def sum(self, lst):
        return sum(lst)

# A different class that contains a different `sum` implementation
class MethodB(object):
    def sum(self, lst):
        s = 0
        for e in lst: s += e
        return s

# Define your tests -- input/expected output pairs
tests = [
    # Input                     Output
    ([1,2,3,4,5],               15),
    ([1,2,3],                   6),
    ([10,11,12,13],             None)
]

# Instantiate your classes
ma = MethodA()
mb = MethodB()

# Run tests
for (i,(inp, exp)) in enumerate(tests):
    res1 = ma.sum(inp)
    res2 = mb.sum(inp)

    if res1 != res2:    print("[Test %d] outputs differed: res1=%s, res2=%s" % (i, res1, res2))
    if exp is not None:
        if res1 != exp: print("[Test %d] res1 output unexpected: res1=%s, exp=%s" % (res1, exp))
        if res2 != exp: print("[Test %d] res2 output unexpected: res2=%s, exp=%s" % (res2, exp))
```

`tests` is a list of tuples, where each tuple is in the form `(input, expected_output)` pair.

The code will run both methods on each input, and compare the outputs.  If the `expected_output` is not `None`, it'll also compare the output from each method to the given expected value.

Of course, this could be modified to test functions instead of methods:

```
def sum1(lst):
    return sum(lst)


def sum2(lst):
    s = 0
    for e in lst: s += e
    return s

tests = [
    # Input                     Output
    ([1,2,3,4,5],               15),
    ([1,2,3],                   6),
    ([10,11,12,13],             None)
]

for (i,(inp, exp)) in enumerate(tests):
    res1 = sum1(inp)
    res2 = sum2(inp)

    if res1 != res2:    print("[Test %d] outputs differed: res1=%s, res2=%s" % (i, res1, res2))
    if exp is not None:
        if res1 != exp: print("[Test %d] res1 output unexpected: res1=%s, exp=%s" % (res1, exp))
        if res2 != exp: print("[Test %d] res2 output unexpected: res2=%s, exp=%s" % (res2, exp))
```

For more comprehensive tests and functionality, you might look into the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) package.